# Unhandled error (spawn ENOENT) during mupx deployment using SSH

Tags: node.js, meteor, deployment, npm, meteor-up

I try to push my Meteor project using Meteor up ([mupx](https://github.com/arunoda/meteor-up/tree/mupx)) but I have an error when I try to deploy:

```
~/git/mupx/bitcoinoutlet# mupx deploy
[..]
Meteor app path : /root/git/satoshiportal
Using buildOptions : {}

events.js:72
     throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event

Error: spawn ENOENT
  at errnoException (child_process.js:1000:11)
  at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit /root/git/satoshiportal
```

This is my `mup.json` configuration file:

```
{
  // Server authentication info
  "servers": [
    {
      "host": "159.203.12.63",
      "username": "root",
      "password": "password",

      "env": {
        "NODE_ENV": "production"
      }
    }
  ],
   "ssl": {
    "certificate": "./bundle.crt",
    "key": "./private.key",
    "port": 443
  },

  // Install MongoDB on the server. Does not destroy the local MongoDB on future setups
  "setupMongo": true,
  "appName": "satoshiportal",
  "app": "/root/git/satoshiportal",

  "env": {
    "PORT": 80,
    "ROOT_URL": "https://www.bitcoinoutlet.com",
    "MAIL_URL": "smtp://......"
  },

  "deployCheckWaitTime": 15,
  "enableUploadProgressBar": true
}
```

And finally, versions:

```
~/git/mupx/bitcoinoutlet# npm --version
3.8.1
~/git/mupx/bitcoinoutlet# node --version
v0.10.29
```

I didn't fount how to retrieve current mupx version but I tried with a lots of version (from 1.1 for 1.5) and my last update was `npm install mupx@1.5.1 -g` (so it's probably `1.5.1`)

Mupx logs give me :
`[159.203.12.63] sudo: unable to resolve host bitcoinoutlet`

I have nothing except the unhandled error and this log. I really don't know what to do next.

Thank

Comment: In mupx git repo there is similar issue https://github.com/arunoda/meteor-up/issues/980.

Answer (score 0):

Yesterday, I worked on using mupx and ran into similar `Error: spawn ENOENT` error, in different context.

I installed the *build-essential* C/C++ compiler package on the server:

`sudo apt-get install build-essential`

Worked for me!